# notion of a current object of the enclosing class

Tags: c++, c++11

I m studying Bjarne's book and look for Member Types of Class.
**A nested class has access to members of its enclosing class, even to private members (just as a
member function has), but has no notion of a current object of the enclosing class.**

 But why I dont get any error when I build following code.

```
template<typename T>
class Tree
{
private:
    using value_type = T;

    class Node
    {
    private:
        Node* right;
        value_type value;
    public:
        void Node_Function(Tree*);
    };
    Node* top;

public:
    void X_f()
    {

    }
};

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::Node::Node_Function(Tree* p)
{
    top = right; //I suppose to get error here like "error : 
                 // no object of type Tree specified"
}
```

Comment: You need to call `Node_function` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one rule that dictates that if a member of class template is not used, then that member is *not* instantiated. That applies to your situation.

You're not calling `Node_Function()`, so the compiler doesn't instantiate it, hence it doesn't see the problem. The function is still parsed for syntax check which is correct — it doesn't attempt to know what `right` is, as it could be a variable, a function name, anything.

[Here is a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c94ef62a6c05f0e) which gives error on calling it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Why did you remove the example? It was good! I've stolen it now since you obviously don't want it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There were competition between so many edits. It is there now. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: Not really. I just removed invalid characters from your URL, then you added them back in, then I removed them again. Then you took out the entire link for some reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because of concurrent edits, the link was not working because of invalid characters.

Comment: @Nawaz: ... which I removed twice! The link was correct at the time you removed it. Refresh faster! :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't attempted to use that function template, so nothing happens.

If you'd debugged with and provided a [testcase](http://sscce.org) with a `main` function invoking this problematic code, you'd have seen the error message you seek.

### - [Like this…](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c94ef62a6c05f0e)

Comment: ahh thanks. You suggest me using unit test or something, I already asked that to @Nawaz. Thank you

Comment: @VitoCarleone: Not really a unit test, though a testcase is a similar sort of beast. Just when you have a problem like this, make sure that you test it with a short example (you were _so_ nearly there!) that _actually runs the function you're testing_ (this bit you were missing). Syntax checks and (semantic checks for non-templates) alone are not always sufficient.